# cant update software or connect to software servers (universe etc)

Tags: updates, connection

It says

```
Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

when I type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` in the terminal.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have another process downloading and installing programs. First try looking for something that may be updating/installing. If you can't find anything, rebooting your machine and starting again may help. However, if none of that works, try killing whichever process has lock, and then configuring any programs that may have downloaded but weren't installed.

```
sudo fuser -vki /var/lib/dpkg/lock; sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

[Source](http://mirkolofio.wordpress.com/2012/03/28/unlock-varlibdpkglock-when-youre-locked-out/)
Note: Please read the source. It offers a lot of good information that you should know.